# Почему не получается десериализовать Json?

Tags: c#, json

Зашел в тупик с десериализацией Json, подскажите, почему?

Делаю всё как по мануалу, онлайн сервисам и многочисленным описаниям, но результата пока нет.

Вот Json, который мне надо разобрать:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1211,
    "minut": 15,
    "dateTime": "2018-11-16T11:52:40.8417827"
    }
]
```

Вот класс:

```
public class TimeIn
    {
    //https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp
    //[JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("minut")]
    public int Minut { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот так десериализую ответ:

```
TimeIn time = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeIn>(content));
```

А так пытаюсь увидеть значение:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!!!  " + time.Minut);
```

Было уже несколько вариантов кода, но результат один - при отладке, после десериализации, на следующую точку останова выполнение приложения не переходит.

Буду рад любому совету! Спасибо!

Comment: например для  подобии дебага можно глянуть валидную строку json. сделайте экземпляр класса и сериализуйте в строку и посмотрите ее

Comment: в проблема в том что вы десериализуете  массив json просто у вас массив с 1 элементом

Comment: List<TimeIn> time = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TimeIn>>(content));

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! Со строкой не получается. Всё то же самое. Массив я пробовал изначально,и так же без успеха :( Сейчас попробую Ваш вариант со списком.

Comment: у себя запустил все отлично отрабатывает.

Comment: `TimeIn[] time = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeIn[]>(content));`?

Comment: Так делал. После этой строки код не выполнялся. Ошибок то же не было.

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Со списком всё получилось! Значение возвращается! `foreach (TimeIn t in time)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!!!! " + t.Minut);
                }`

Comment: просто из строки уберите первый символ [ и последний символ ] и ваш старый код будет работать

Comment: Вот так ещё оказывается можно. Попробую. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий код

```
TimeIn time = new TimeIn()
            {
                Id = 34,
                Minut = 45,
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<TimeIn>() {time});
            Console.WriteLine($"json string \n {json}");
            //выведет json строку [{"Id":34,"Minut":45,"DateTime":"2018-11-16T12:23:36.3927226+02:00"}]
            // и обрантно

            var col = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TimeIn>>(json);
            // так как col  коллекция
            foreach (var t in col)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"t.Minut {t.Minut}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить 
[Serializable]
над вашим классом TimeIn

Answer (score 0):

Andrey, используй силу аннотации:

[DataContract(Name = "TimeIn")] -для класса

[DataMember(Name = "minut")] - для полей

Comment: Объясните, какое это имеет отношение к вопросу автора? На мой взгляд никакого: json.net не учитывает регистр в написании полей (можете проверить). Тогда какую проблему вы решали своим ответом?